# Is homosexuality a choice as per Islam?

Tags: sin, punishment, homosexuality

In my experience, many Muslims hold the view that homosexuality ( regarding merely the sexual orientation - that is to say attraction to one's same sex), is a choice. What evidence exists to support this view if it is true?

From what I can tell, the evidence that exists around us seems to suggest that it is not a choice. I don't think all the gay people around us are engaged in some kind of conspiracy to collectively lie about not having a choice.

If it was a choice, wouldn't I as a heterosexual person, be able to one day legitimately decide to live as a homosexual?

How does one choose to be attracted to the same sex?

I personally haven't found that I can make myself acquire any sexual feelings towards my gender, so how can others do this?

Comment: What's with the down voting? At least comment / reply.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK scholars don't consider being sexually attracted to the same gender as a sin, they do however consider that acting upon that sexual attraction is a sin.

> Al-Bukhaari (5269) and Muslim (127) also narrated from Abu Hurayrah
>   (may Allah be pleased with him), that the Prophet (blessings and peace
>   of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah, may He be glorified and exalted,
>   will forgive my ummah for whatever crosses their minds so long as they
>   do not act upon it or speak of it.”

Resisting thoughts of carrying out sinful actions is rewarded, this proofs that sinful thoughts do not gain incur sin and the urges that we experience also do not define who we are.

> Al-Bukhaari (6491) and Muslim (131) narrated from Ibn ‘Abbaas (may
>   Allah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (blessings and peace of
>   Allah be upon him) said, relating from his Lord, may He be glorified
>   and exalted: “Allah decreed good deeds and bad deeds, then He
>   explained that. Whoever thinks of doing a good deed then does not do
>   it, Allah will write it down as one complete good deed. If he thinks
>   of doing a good deed and then does it, Allah [may He be glorified and
>   exalted] will write it down between ten and seven hundred fold, or
>   many more. If he thinks of doing a bad deed then he does not do it,
>   Allah will write it down as one complete good deed, and if he thinks
>   of it then does it, Allah will write it down as one bad deed.”

There has been an experiment were homosexual pornographic films were shown to heterosexual men, some got aroused some didn't, those who did, still considered them selves as heterosexual, therefore it could be that a minor attraction can be there but a person building upon it may make them think that it isn't a choice but developing that attraction i.e. increasing would be considered a sin.(Sorry can't find source)

> Allah wants to make clear to you [the lawful from the unlawful] and
>   guide you to the [good] practices of those before you and to accept
>   your repentance. And Allah is Knowing and Wise. Allah wants to accept
>   your repentance, but those who follow [their] passions want you to
>   digress [into] a great deviation. And Allah wants to lighten for you
>   [your difficulties]; and mankind was created weak. [Quran 4:26 - 4:28]

The fact of the matter is, that whether it is a choice or not, giving in to it is a sin, Muslims might be attracted to something by nature or not but God sets the guidelines as to whether it can be pursued and how.

That which we cannot pursue would always have a reason behind it, we may know what it is, we may not therefore sometimes we hypothesise, but ultimately God knows best.

> “And it may be that you dislike a thing which is good for you and that
>   you like a thing which is bad for you. Allah knows but you do not
>   know.” (AI-Baqarah, 2:216)

Comment: But if it is not a choice, why must people suffer and resist their desires, while heterosexual people are not burdened the same way? How is it fair that only one party can satisfy their sexual needs while the other must suppress their feelings?

Comment: @JohnDoe Whether it is a choice or not does not really matter, this life is a test, we are all tested in a different way, each person is capable of dealing with burdens on different levels and God has told us that he does no burden a sole with more than what it can handle. Just because we have an urge it does not mean we have to submit to it. Some have an urge to save lives others a have the urge to end it, why must the later  suppress their urges.

Comment: I think the obvious answer to your analogy regarding why should the ones who have the urge to end lives should suppress such urges is that because it is harmful to society to allow these people to follow through with their urges. If you were to turn that around on homosexuality and make the claim that the act of homosexual intercourse necessarily harms society, that would require evidence. But you haven't made this claim as far as I know so that's fine.