# Sexual orientation

Tags: relationships, sexuality

Is it haram to be attracted to the same gender but not have sex with them? For instance having a crush on a female and being female but not dating them or have sex.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Does [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49884/is-homosexuality-a-choice-as-per-islam/49894#49894) help?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu alaikum my dear brother,
First of all you need to understand that Allah has not only asked you not to do adultery, but he has also asked us not to go near the adultery.
So whether a male or female , sexually or physically getting attracted is considered as adultery. So so even if you are attracted towards other gender it is highly e disliked by the Allah. And in the matter of same gender (homosexual) it is worse. 
You may think that I am just attracted that's not a sin . But it is a master plan of shaitan . Which will definitely ruin your life and imaan. So so stay away from that attraction.
Allah knows best